# Mysql + C# перенос информации

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Как из MySql phpmyadmin извлечь информацию из таблицы и перенести в `Label`?

Суть кода, что при нажатии на условно `button1` извлекалась информация из БД и выводилась в лэйблы.

```
    private void obnova_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DB db = new DB();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `pay` WHERE `money` = @M,`comment` = @C, `name` = @N,  `date` = @D", db.getConnection());

        command.Parameters.Add("@M", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =label5.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@C", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label6.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@N", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label7.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@D", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label8.Text;

        db.openConnection();
        string name = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        if (name != null)
        {
            label5.Text ="";
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("");
        }
        db.closeConnection();
    }
```

Comment: уровень абстракции вопроса засшкаливает)  подкл. к базе-> выполнить запрос к нужной таб. -> обработать результат-> вывести результат на свою форму 
И каждый шаг это сам по себе большой вопрос требующий изучения

Comment: суть то я понимаю, но не могу найти или не правильно ищу информацию в интернете. Где бы можно было подробнее ознакомиться с этим? Сам проект подключен к бд и получилось закинуть информацию из формы в таблицу, а вот как извлечь информацию, это уже вопрос)

Comment: Ну так покажите код, как вы закидываете информацию в БД и как хотите извлечь, добавьте как можно больше деталей в вопрос - тогда шанс получить нужный ответ быдет выше.

Comment: код представил.

Comment: Условия в запросе объединяют логическими операторами в одно выражение логического типа, а не перечисляют через запятую. Типа ```MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `pay` WHERE `money` = @M AND `comment` = @C AND `name` = @N AND `date` = @D", db.getConnection());``` PS. `date` - зарезервированное слово, и называть так поле таблицы - это искать себе геморроя...

Comment: спасибо за дополнительную информацию, учту

Comment: но все же не понятно, как сделать выгрузку информации, буду рад, если сможете подсказать источник изучения вопроса)